# Problems enabling dtr in my serial communication program

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, serial-port

I'm making a program which communicates with a serial port(RS232 mainly but in this instance I'm using a usb device). Right now I'm having a problem when enabling DTR.

```
private void CheckBox_DTR_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(COMport != null)
    {
        if (CheckBox_DTR.Checked)
        {
          COMport.DtrEnable = true;
        }
        else
        {
          COMport.DtrEnable = false;
        }

    }

}
```

In this part of my code I'm enabling DTR if checkbox gets checked. When I checked the pin voltage everything seems to be ok because voltage increases when I enable it. But there's the problem: when I enable DTR using other terminals the device throws out some info but when I do this with my program it doesn't send that info.

[My program](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QBxJR.jpg)

[Other Serial Terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2L5nN.jpg)

As you can see other terminal has some additional info that device sends out upon enabling DTR. So I'm not completely sure what should I do to receive that info from the device(do I need some additional code or something)...

Comment: Please don't post images of your results. You can add the results directly to the question as text.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind next time. But I had to post pictures because I wasn't able to copy the text from the terminals.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when using DTR you need to turn hardware handshaking on.  I would try setting `COMport.Handshake = Handshake.XOnXOff;`.

According to MSDN [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.ports.serialport.dtrenable?view=netframework-4.8):

> Data Terminal Ready (DTR) is typically enabled during XON/XOFF software handshaking and Request to Send/Clear to Send (RTS/CTS) hardware handshaking, and modem communications.

Comment: Should I close the port before changing hanshaking or can I leave it open?

Comment: You should be able to do it while the port is open, however, it is best practice to apply all your settings before opening the port.